# Fetch Azure Resources using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to get a list of Azure resources, example, we have the command `Get-AzResourceGroup` to get list of resources. Or `Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01"` to list SQL Servers from a particular Resource Group. How can we do this in Terraform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can use the [data source:azurerm_resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/resources.html) to list the resources with the type in Azure as you want. But as I test, when I add the resource group, it only returns an empty list. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my code. If it works as it shows, then it's the thing which you want and the example would like this:

```
data "azurerm_resources" "example" {
  resource_group_name = "example-resources"
  type                = "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could authenticate with [`Azure CLI with terraform`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurestack/auth/azure_cli.html) and then use the CLI command to get the resources.

```
 az resource list [--location]
                 [--name]
                 [--namespace]
                 [--resource-group]
                 [--resource-type]
                 [--subscription]
                 [--tag]
```

Comment: I know how to do it via 'az cli' and and PowerShell. How can I use them(az cli / PS code) inside terraform template?

Comment: An example would be to write a terraform template to fetch all the Azure SQL servers and update their firewall rules to whitelist certain IP addresses.

Comment: oh got your point, i don't think there is a template as of now https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/sql_server.html